# too many values to unpack (expected 2) | Django

Tags: python, django, model

At first it showed me this error "userdata() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

[image]

then after I just "self" to my code.

```
from snakeladder.models import User
```

from django.http import request

class UserFile:

```
def userdata(self):
    data = User.objects.all()
    return data`enter code here`
```

then it throw me this code.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, Django never return the value as basic string or integer or any other data type. If you want to return any values use "HttpResponse()" pass the value like this.

```
def userdata():
    data = User.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

instaed of this

```
def userdata():
    data = User.objects.all()
    return data
```

Example:

```
def userdata():
    data ="This is the string that I wan to"
    return data
```

You can't do above way you have to use "HttpResponse" like below one.

```
def userdata():
    data ="This is the string that I wan to"
    return HttpResponse(data)
```